# How to get the channel of a image by wx.bitmap

Tags: python, wxpython

I need to get the channel of wx.bitmap. I use the function `GetDepth`. It return 24 all the time , even if I pass a 8depth gray image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use PIL(python image library)'s mode to judge the channels